# Custom cursor image doesn't work in all IEs?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mouse-cursor

I think I have tried different methods suggested all over the internet but nothing worked. This is my current css code:

```
div {
   cursor: url(images/zoomin.cur), auto;
}
```

It works fine except in IE...

Comment: @Spudley, it is 21x32 pixels.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, `cursor` is plain buggy in IE, at least until and including 8

> In Internet Explorer for Windows up to and including version 8, if a
>   relative URI value is specified in an external style sheet file the
>   base URI is considered to be the URI of the document containing the
>   element and not the URI of the style sheet in which the declaration
>   appears.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor

You may want be able to use a `conditional comment` to target IE and then feed it a modified style rule with a different `url`.

Comment: Could include IE9 too.  Not sure.  Was basing my comments on the tests from Sitepoint.

Comment: Currently still buggy in IE 10 as well

Comment: Still buggy in Edge Browser

Answer (score 7):

I solved in this way for the *grab cursor* in Internet Explorer, citing the [@JasonGennaro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419342/2149425)'s answer:

> In Internet Explorer for Windows up to and including version 8, if a
> relative URI value is specified in an external style sheet file the
> base URI is considered to be the URI of the document containing the
> element and not the URI of the style sheet in which the declaration
> appears.

```
.grab_cursor {
    cursor: grab !important; /*Without !important the .cur-file property below will overwrite this and browser will show default cursor*/
    cursor: -moz-grab !important;
    cursor: -webkit-grab !important;
    cursor: url('../img/cursors/openhand.cur'), url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize; /* standard: note the different path for the .cur file */
    cursor: url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize\9; /* IE 8 and below */
    *cursor: url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize; /* IE 7 and below */
    _cursor: url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize; /* IE 6 */
}
```

**Files tree**:

```
index.html
css/style.css -> here the posted code
img/cursors/openhand.cur
```

**Good references**:

- [One](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer)
- [Two](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)
- [Three](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/12/21/cross-browser-css-cursor-images-in-depth/)

**Working Demo**:

- [Demo](http://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/full/rxvgwQ/)

Answer (score 2):

Because different browsers treat relative URI's differently, the cursor style allows a list of urls. You can have one path that works for IE and one that works for other browsers:

```
div {
   cursor: url('app/images/zoomin.cur'), url('zoomin.cur'), auto;
}
```

In my setup, the first url works for IE11 (and earlier) because the script that uses the cursor is in 'cgi-bin/app' while the .cur and .css files are in 'app/images'. IE uses the document location as the base, so I need to add more path information to locate the cursor file. The second url works in Firefox because .cur and .css are in the same location and Firefox uses the .css location as the base, so additional path info is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

From msdn documentation:

> url(uri) 
>   Internet Explorer 6 and later. Cursor is defined by the
>   author, using a custom URI, such as url('mycursor.cur'). **Cursors of
>   type .CUR and .ANI are the only supported cursor types**.

Answer (score 0):

from : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

> The cursor property is supported in all major browsers.
>
> Note: Opera 9.3 and Safari 3 do not support URL values.
>
> Note: The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8
>   requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit".

Answer (score 0):

To work in IE you need specify full path to CUR file. E.g.:

```
html {
    cursor: url("../img/cursor.png"), url("http://www.example.com/dist/assets/img/cursor.cur"), default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one work for me proved in IE10, INDEXED in the  of index.html( you must use absolute routes)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container{
    cursor: url(http://path/of/folder/image.cur), default !important;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced curser pointer rendering problem in IE. Below are my solutions.

There is 2 things which you need to make sure.

1. Curser file should be .cur or .ani files.
2. You need to give full url image path. i.e.http://abc.in/static/images/demo.cur

You can face a problem of curser origin start position. SO  you can solve that problem by using https://www.cursor.cc. website.
it has an check box of **hotspot (where the mouse clicks)** by using you can decide your pointer position.

Hope all pointer problem can be solve by above details.

Answer (score -1):

I tried using .ani and .gif and it is working. It should go like this:

```
body {
cursor: url(images/dog.ani), url(images/dog.gif), progress !important;
}
```

This css works for my website in chrome, firefox and IE.