# Using external images for CSS custom cursors

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to use external image URLs for CSS custom cursors? The following example doesn't work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.test {
  background:gray;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  cursor:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/POL_apple.jpg');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Cursor Image CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css)

Comment: Similar to the use of favicon.ico icons, there are limits to what kind of image can be used for your custom cursor. Try using a smaller image.

Comment: @Zeaklous- Not a dup at all- I'm asking about external images

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It wasn't working because your image was too big - there are restrictions on the image dimensions. In Firefox, for example, the size limit is 128x128px. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#icon_size_limits) for more details.

Additionally, you also have to add in `auto`.

[**jsFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/5/) - note that's an actual image, and not a default cursor.

```css
.test {
  background:gray;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: More info on size restrictions: "In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms." (From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor%2Furl)

Comment: Actually, you do not necessarily need to add "auto" as a second value, it could be anything from CSS cursor values, url() excluded of course. It works as a callback if the url() for some reason does not work.

Comment: @SilverRingvee you mean **fallback** if the url... ;) thanks

Comment: Note that `svg` files with `width` and `height` values have to explicitly set those values within the 32x32 limit to show up. They will NOT auto scale to fit within the browser requirements.

Comment: would be nice if one could simply get the standard cursor but use a filter on it or something

Comment: updated link to icon size limitations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#icon_size_limits

Answer (score 9):

I would put this as a comment, but I don't have the rep for it. What Josh Crozier answered is correct, but for IE .cur and .ani are the only supported formats for this. So you should probably have a fallback just in case:

```
.test {
    cursor:url("http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif"), url(foo.cur), auto;
}
```

Comment: [Working example for IE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419314/custom-cursor-image-doesnt-work-in-all-ies#answer-35068297).

Comment: NOT THE CASE ANYMORE - NOWADAYS YOU CAN USE PNG ETC :)

Answer (score 5):

Originally from a [Codepen pen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uCwfB) by [Chris Coyier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363927/chris-coyier) of Codepen/CSS-Tricks

```css
.auto            { cursor: auto; }
.default         { cursor: default; }
.none            { cursor: none; }
.context-menu    { cursor: context-menu; }
.help            { cursor: help; }
.pointer         { cursor: pointer; }
.progress        { cursor: progress; }
.wait            { cursor: wait; }
.cell            { cursor: cell; }
.crosshair       { cursor: crosshair; }
.text            { cursor: text; }
.vertical-text   { cursor: vertical-text; }
.alias           { cursor: alias; }
.copy            { cursor: copy; }
.move            { cursor: move; }
.no-drop         { cursor: no-drop; }
.not-allowed     { cursor: not-allowed; }
.all-scroll      { cursor: all-scroll; }
.col-resize      { cursor: col-resize; }
.row-resize      { cursor: row-resize; }
.n-resize        { cursor: n-resize; }
.e-resize        { cursor: e-resize; }
.s-resize        { cursor: s-resize; }
.w-resize        { cursor: w-resize; }
.ns-resize       { cursor: ns-resize; }
.ew-resize       { cursor: ew-resize; }
.ne-resize       { cursor: ne-resize; }
.nw-resize       { cursor: nw-resize; }
.se-resize       { cursor: se-resize; }
.sw-resize       { cursor: sw-resize; }
.nesw-resize     { cursor: nesw-resize; }
.nwse-resize     { cursor: nwse-resize; }

body {
  text-align: center;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";

}
.cursors {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cursors > div {
  flex: 150px;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.cursors > div:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

HTML CSSResult
EDIT ON
.svg {
  cursor: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/heart.svg), auto;
}

.svg-base64 {
  cursor: url(data:text/html;base64,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), auto;
}

.png-base64 {
  cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,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"), auto;
}

.png {
  cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/heart.png"), auto;
}

.gif {
  cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/tina.gif"), auto;
}

.cursors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cursors > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Cursors of CSS</h1>

<div class="cursors">
    <div class="auto">auto</div>
    <div class="default">default</div>
    <div class="none">none</div>
    <div class="context-menu">context-menu</div>
    <div class="help">help</div>
    <div class="pointer">pointer</div>
    <div class="progress">progress</div>
    <div class="wait">wait</div>
    <div class="cell">cell</div>
    <div class="crosshair">crosshair</div>
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="vertical-text">vertical-text</div>
    <div class="alias">alias</div>
    <div class="copy">copy</div>
    <div class="move">move</div>
    <div class="no-drop">no-drop</div>
    <div class="not-allowed">not-allowed</div>
    <div class="all-scroll">all-scroll</div>
    <div class="col-resize">col-resize</div>
    <div class="row-resize">row-resize</div>
    <div class="n-resize">n-resize</div>
    <div class="s-resize">s-resize</div>
    <div class="e-resize">e-resize</div>
    <div class="w-resize">w-resize</div>
    <div class="ns-resize">ns-resize</div>
    <div class="ew-resize">ew-resize</div>
    <div class="ne-resize">ne-resize</div>
    <div class="nw-resize">nw-resize</div>
    <div class="se-resize">se-resize</div>
    <div class="sw-resize">sw-resize</div>
    <div class="nesw-resize">nesw-resize</div>
    <div class="nwse-resize">nwse-resize</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>Custom Image</h1>
<div class="cursors">
  <div class="svg"><p>SVG</p></div>
  <div class="svg-base64">Base 64 SVG</div>
  <div class="png-base64">Base 64 PNG</div>
  <div class="png">PNG</div>
  <div class="gif">GIF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 For exceptional code! Although an explanation for what each line does / means would have been helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
cursor:url('http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif'), auto
```

NOTE 1: 
In some cases you should consider setting the offset (anchor):

`cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif) 10 3, auto;`

in this exmple, we set offsetx to 10 and offsety to 3 (from top left), so the pointer finger will be anchor.
fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5kxt1j98/
(you can see the difference by moving cursor to top left of container)

---

NOTE 2: THE MAX CURSOR SIZE IS 128*128, recommended one is below 32*32.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to add the pointer
eg:

```css
div{
    cursor: url('cursorurl.png'), pointer;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `pointer`, `auto` would be more appropriate. And a valuable thing to mention is that the max cursor image size for Firefox is currently 128x128 pixels, no more --But you can make it within that range.