# How to make cursor style to circle using html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm building a drawing app, and I want a cursor in form of circle.  I searched HTML5 style to make cursor default, pointer etc, but I need it to be a circle.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be done by CSS.

Check out the following snippet and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x797dkth/)

```css
#circle64 {
  cursor: url('http://www.iconsdownload.net/icons/64/16574-black-circle.png'), pointer;
}
#circle32 {
  cursor: url('http://www.iconsdownload.net/icons/32/16574-black-circle.png'), pointer;
}
#circle24 {
  cursor: url('http://www.iconsdownload.net/icons/24/16574-black-circle.png'), pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id='circle64'>
  Cursor will
  <br>be</br>different here.
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id='circle32'>
  Cursor will
  <br>be</br>different here.
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id='circle24'>
  Cursor will
  <br>be</br>different here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an image as cursor, by using this css property

```
cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
```

for example if you have some input and you want to show round cursor on it , you should use png image

```
input{
cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

check this jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/pwy51Ly8/

Comment: you need to use image as cursor for example image like this http://s30.postimg.org/q2s76q6u5/Reload_arrow_32.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS cursor wait

```
div {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

or

```
div {
 cursor: url("your custom cursor image"), auto;
}
```

Comment: cursor :wait is not matching need, i tried loading image, but nothing happens

Comment: You can use animated gif or any png file in cursor:url(your png or gif)

Comment: make sure your given url is currect exampe: cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif), auto;

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors) link
"It wasn't working because your image was too big - there are restrictions on the image dimensions. In Firefox, for example, the size limit is 128x128px"