# How to use a svg as the cursor

Tags: css, svg

Im trying to use a svg image as the cursor when hovering over a certain div but I cant get it working. Ive read that it should be as simple as adding this :

```
cursor: url(http://elusivethemes.com/assets/down.svg), auto;
```

But it wont seem to work. The strange thing is it works if i use a different svg image from a different url.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try downloading the resource and hosting it locally.

Comment: @HunterTurner I wouldn't qualify this as a duplicate of [Using external images for CSS customer cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors) as that question only mentions about image-based cursors. The current issue happens due to the fact that the image used is an SVG without declared dimensions. Therefore, I wouldn't flag it as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

> Starting with Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1),
>   Gecko also supports the SVG image format for cursors. **However, the SVG
>   image must contain a length-valued (not percentage-valued) height and
>   width on its root SVG node.** JavaScript, CSS animation, and declarative
>   SMIL inside an SVG image are ignored; you can't use SVG to create an
>   animated cursor, for example.

Therefore, you should explicitly declare the height and width in your .svg file.

The .svg you provided has no dimensions declared as you can see:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Capa_1" viewBox="0 0 320.995 320.995" x="0px" y="0px" height="200" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xml:space="preserve" viewbox="0 0 320.995 320.995" version="1.1">
```

If you add the width and height attributes, you should be fine.

**Just make sure you don't declare the dimensions with percentages**

Comment: Ok great thankyou. Do i declare the width and height in the css or the svg itself ?

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe it has to be in the SVG itself. However I would try to do it with css just in case