# How to use material icons as mouse cursor image

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have a scenario in which i have to use a specific material icon as cursor pointer for a mat-button. I don't have any idea how to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

```html
 <button mat-button>
 <button>
```

Comment: Can you use the svg version?

Comment: Nope we can use

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it using Material. You need to update the CSS by adding:

```
you-mat-element {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

I forked [the original Angular example](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview) and I made the change to have a live Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eynqmo

Comment: I am quite late to this, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962081/css-cursor-pointer-with-svg-image it might be possible. If you have a look at their repository (e.g. https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/src/action/3d_rotation/materialicons), it's a SVG file. So one would *just* have to get the SVG data, encode it properly and set as URL source via CSS I believe. It does involve some work though.

Answer (score 1):

In the css file add the following line into your css class:

`.your-css-class { cursor: URL('path-to-png-or-svg-file'), auto; }`

Note that the `png` or `SVG` file can be downloaded from the google material icon page at the following link:
[Google Material Icons](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline)