# Custom Cursor SVG Blurry

Tags: css, svg

I have a custom cursor defined using an inline SVG image of two rotated rectangles. While it works, I'm surprised to find it blurry in Chrome. Is there something I can do to sharpen the edges?

```
.not-allowed{cursor:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNiAxNiIgd2lkdGg9IjE2IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjE2Ij48cmVjdCB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg0NSkiIHg9IjkuMjc2MyIgeT0iLTgiIHdpZHRoPSI0LjA3NDkiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIGZpbGw9IiMyMjIiLz48cmVjdCB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMzUpIiB4PSItMi4wMzc0IiB5PSItMTkuMzE0IiB3aWR0aD0iNC4wNzQ5IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjE2IiBmaWxsPSIjMjIyIi8+PC9zdmc+') 8 8, not-allowed}
```

Made more readable based on @enxaneta's link:

```
.not-allowed{cursor:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' width='16' height='16'%3E%3Crect transform='rotate%2845%29' x='9.2763' y='-8' width='4.0749' height='16' fill='%23222'/%3E%3Crect transform='rotate%28135%29' x='-2.0374' y='-19.314' width='4.0749' height='16' fill='%23222'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 8 8, not-allowed}
```

Comment: Does not look blurry to me at all in chrome: https://codepen.io/ArSn/pen/KKpyRWV - can you post a screenshot of the blurry one?

Comment: This is what it looks like in Chrome on Windows. https://imgur.com/a/BU0Uq7u

Comment: Do you by any chance have a very large cursor configured and/or a low screen resolution? The contents of your SVG seem to be pixel-sizes instead of percentages (which would make the SVG actually scalable). My recommendation is therefore to rework the SVG and use percentages and see if the problem persists for you

Comment: please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962081/css-cursor-pointer-with-svg-image#45966695 Also don't forget to open the exampe: https://jsfiddle.net/xhk4zo8y/

Comment: @ArSeN default cursor configs and a 4k monitor with 250% scaling. Maybe that might be the issue for me. I'm interested in using percents instead of pixels, but I can't find how to do that. Do you share a link to something that uses percents?

Comment: @enxaneta The final answer is actually blurry on my setup too. It's showing up where as that guy's wasn't, it's just blurry. The link on the post to https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris was really informative and something I'm going to incorporate.

Comment: @GFL here is a good guide on making SVGs scalable: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ - please report back whether this solves your problem or not. Also, if you reset scaling to 100% (so no upscaling) I am guessing the effect will vanish for you. Still none the less I recommend making the SVG scalable so it always works