# When hover image use custom cursor and point at link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, cursor

I have a specific idea/question and did not yet find any code which I can customize to get what I want.

I have an image, and in that image is a text link. When you hover over the image I want a custom cursor to appear and point with it's arrow towards the text link. Is something like this possible and maybe a piece of code were I can work with?

Robert

Comment: I think the example you can see at this link does exactly what you want: https://css-tricks.com/can-you-rotate-the-cursor-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the closest thing to your description would be [HTML Image Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)

Be aware that this functionality is not responsive, meaning if you scale image, the areas will remain original size.
The easiest way to overcome this is to use SVG image. You can find various tutorials on the web, eg. [this one](http://thenewcode.com/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps)

Comment: Check this out and use css to achieve what you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962081/css-cursor-pointer-with-svg-image