# D3v6 custom cursor

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 supports to change the cursor with the help of inline attributes, like:

```
...

node.style("cursor", "pointer")

...
```

Lets assume I want a custom cursor. A .PNG or .SVG for example. How can I achieve this? Unfortunately I can´t use CSS for this purpose as the custom cursor depends on JavaScript functions which are not always used.

In CSS it would be possible with:

```
node{
cursor: url("custom.png"), auto
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962081/css-cursor-pointer-with-svg-image/45966695

Comment: This might be useful as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Comment: Hello @MichaelRovinsky thanks for both hints. But as I mentioned my problem isn´t that I can´t use a custom cursor with the help of CSS. I need to know how can I toggle it either in D3 or Javascript. CSS only works for this or that but not for toggle needs.

Comment: You can specify 2 classes in CSS and change the element class on toggle