# Set cursor as an svg

Tags: css, svg

- I ensured my svg size (height, width) [is smaller than the limit.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966695/7123519)
- I ensured the svg itself is valid by rendering it in html.

I must be missing something because it doesn't work.

**This one works:**

```css
.container2 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="black" fill="white" transform="scale(1 -1)"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 0 0-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path></svg>') 12 12, auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2"></div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="black" fill="white" transform="scale(1 -1)"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 0 0-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path></svg>
```

**This one doesn't work ... why?**

```css
 
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: gold;
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="#000000" height="24" width="24" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 330 330" xml:space="preserve"> <g id="XMLID_87_"> <path id="XMLID_88_" d="M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111   C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01   c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394   C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30   c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z"/> <path id="XMLID_91_" d="M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15   s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z"/> </g> </svg>') 12 12, pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="#000000" height="24" width="24" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 330 330" xml:space="preserve"> <g id="XMLID_87_"> <path id="XMLID_88_" d="M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111   C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01   c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394   C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30   c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z"/> <path id="XMLID_91_" d="M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15   s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z"/> </g> </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error for `cursor` property. Use this instead:

```
cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' fill='%23000000' height='24' width='24' version='1.1' id='Layer_1' viewBox='0 0 330 330' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cg id='XMLID_87_'%3E%3Cpath id='XMLID_88_' d='M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111 C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01 c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394 C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30 c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z'/%3E%3Cpath id='XMLID_91_' d='M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15 s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") 12 12, pointer;
```

Comment: That works. But can you explain why? I used the same syntax in both examples, but only one works... It seems like you just escaped the `>` and `<` characters. In my first example, I didn't escape those characters either, but it still worked.

Comment: The url-encoded ouput of second svg is not correct. Open in it is a browser and you'll see this error message:
`
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 90: AttValue: ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
`

Answer (score 2):

Your first SVG has `fill="black"`

Your second SVG has `fill="#000000"`

That **#** needs to be *escaped* with `%23` because a # has another meaning in URLs
and `cursor:url( ... )` processes the SVG as if it is a URL

In older browsers you also needed to escape **<** and **>**
That is no longer required, but ofcourse *old* tools will still do so.

All I changed in *your* code below was *one* **#** to **%23**

```css
 
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: gold;
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="%23000000" height="24" width="24" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 330 330" xml:space="preserve"> <g id="XMLID_87_"> <path id="XMLID_88_" d="M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111   C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01   c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394   C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30   c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z"/> <path id="XMLID_91_" d="M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15   s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z"/> </g> </svg>') 12 12, pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="#000000" height="24" width="24" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 330 330" xml:space="preserve"> <g id="XMLID_87_"> <path id="XMLID_88_" d="M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111   C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01   c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394   C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30   c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z"/> <path id="XMLID_91_" d="M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15   s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z"/> </g> </svg>
```

Notes:

- the attributes `xmlns:xlink`, `xml:`, `version`, `id` can all be removed,
  they are relics of older syntax and SVG drawing tools
- 0.NNN precision in `<path d="..."` is ridiculous, it is stuffing 1000 "pixels" into 1 only making your CPU work harder
  Use https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/# to set `number of decimals` to 0 and minimize the `d-path`

Answer (score 0):

I went to [this website](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) and pasted in my svg:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="#000000" height="24" width="24" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 330 330" xml:space="preserve"> <g id="XMLID_87_"> <path id="XMLID_88_" d="M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111   C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01   c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394   C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30   c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z"/> <path id="XMLID_91_" d="M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15   s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z"/> </g> </svg>
```

Then I copied the `url` part from the *Ready for CSS* and pasted it in my css like:

```css
cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' fill='%23000000' height='24' width='24' version='1.1' id='Layer_1' viewBox='0 0 330 330' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cg id='XMLID_87_'%3E%3Cpath id='XMLID_88_' d='M325.606,304.394L223.329,202.116c16.707-21.256,26.682-48.04,26.682-77.111 C250.011,56.077,193.934,0,125.005,0C56.077,0,0,56.077,0,125.006C0,193.933,56.077,250.01,125.005,250.01 c29.07,0,55.855-9.975,77.111-26.681l102.277,102.277C307.322,328.536,311.161,330,315,330s7.678-1.464,10.606-4.394 C331.465,319.749,331.465,310.251,325.606,304.394z M30,125.006C30,72.619,72.619,30,125.005,30 c52.387,0,95.006,42.619,95.006,95.005c0,52.386-42.619,95.005-95.006,95.005C72.619,220.01,30,177.391,30,125.006z'/%3E%3Cpath id='XMLID_91_' d='M155.005,110.006h-15v-15c0-8.284-6.716-15-15-15s-15,6.716-15,15v15h-15c-8.284,0-15,6.716-15,15 s6.716,15,15,15h15v15c0,8.284,6.716,15,15,15s15-6.716,15-15v-15h15c8.284,0,15-6.716,15-15S163.289,110.006,155.005,110.006z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
```