# Make a cursor an image

Tags: css, html, custom-cursor

I'm trying to get the cursor to change when I hover over an element but I cannot seem to get it to work.

My code so far:

```css
.more_scrolly{
  cursor: url("images/cross.png"), auto!important;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one" class="more_scrolly" >learn more</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect and you need to provide a fallback in case your provided cursor fails to load.

```
cursor: url("images/cross.png"), auto;
```

Comment: Okay ive corrected my syntax, saved my work, and refreshed the page. It still dosent work. Ive checked the file location and all that no good

Comment: Could it be the file type

Answer (score 0):

```css
.CursorClass {
  cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif), auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="CursorClass" >Click Me </a>
```