# why can i only use my cursor tag in embedded html?

Tags: css, cursor

I tried to change the cursor on my html website with the "cursor" property, but I can only do it embedded, but I want to put it in my css stylesheet. Is that possible? 
This is the code that I put between the style tags

```
* {
    cursor: url('plaatjes/cake.cur'), default;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

changing ur cursor is possbile yeah.
There are different possibilities why ur cursor image is not showing up (image type, image size, image url for
example..)

Try this accepted answer:

[so accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551357/2720657)

This example changes the cursor for a specific div, if u use this like u have done before (with *) it should work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cursor on whole page, this should work:

first fix width/height of html and body element,

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

then:

```
* {
        cursor: url('plaatjes/cake.cur'), default;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because it will mess up the entire document