# Custom mouse cursor with clickable option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a custom mouse cursor like this website:

```
https://blab.studio
```

When you enter your mouse in the body of the page, the curse pointer will be hidden and website show's the customized cursor.
Can you show me right code or script for this purpose?

I want to be able to click with this cursor, just like the website I sent.

Regards.

Comment: Use `cursor: url('image_url');` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Comment: use css for this

Comment: refer this : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this using the CSS property:

```
.myclass {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

For example, if you want to change the cursor in your entire website:

```
body {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

You can use **gif**, **svg**, **png** ... as the image.

In order to hide the cursor use:

```
 cursor: none;
```