# custom cursor image not changing for mouseover html5 canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas

Specifically I have an html5 canvas and I am trying to change the cursor image to a custom image on mouseover over the element, but it's not working. I put it in the CSS that cursor:url, url, default for the element with the particular ID. The last tag "default" works because when I changed from default to all-scroll it changed. When I checked Network in console it's loading in the file I want to change the cursor to, too.

Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
#sketchpad {
  border: #cec0fc 3px solid;
  background: white;
  cursor: url("../images/you/brush.png"), url("/gentle_mollusc/assets/images/you/brush.png"), default;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- drawing pad goes here -->
<canvas id="sketchpad"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: hi @volt, added

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are restrictions on the size and dimensions of the image you can use for custom cursor, the restrictions are browser dependent. (Firefox only allows 128*128px).
Check the following URL:
[Using URL values for the cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor%2Furl)

Please check if the following thread helps you solve your problem or answers your question:
[Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)