# Custom Cursor Not Working HTA (HTML Application)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I'm making an HTML5 game using HTA (HTML Application) and I'm trying to import a custom cursor. The dimensions of this cursor is 48x48.

```
body{
cursor:url('arrow.cur'), auto;
}
```

I don't know why this isn't working. If someone could help, that'd be great!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551357/10289265

Answer (score 0):

coding is correct but check your folder image path and also [check more reference](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/)