# How to change the cursor when the user clicks?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a custom cursor for a website, which when clicked, anywhere on the page, the cursor changes to another image, until the button is unclicked when it will revert back to the original cursor.

```
body {
    cursor: url('images/cursor.png'), auto;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use an onclick event listener on the body itself.

```js
document.body.onmousedown = () => {
  document.body.style.cursor = "not-allowed"
}

document.body.onmouseup = () => {
  document.body.style.cursor = `pointer`
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: aliceblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I imagine you'd need mouse down/up if you want to revert once the click is complete.

Comment: Yes I, guess you could to that.

Comment: @DBS could you tell me how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:active` on the `html` element:

```css
html:active {
    cursor:pointer; /* url('images/cursor.png') */
}

html {
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>title</h1>
<p>some text</p>
```

Comment: Man I was just thinking if active would work, How about event delegation here? Will children cause issues?

Comment: @TheFool what kind of issues?

Comment: if you have children inside, and you active actuallly the child and not the html tag itself. Lets say a button or input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.default_cursor {
    cursor: url('images/default.gif'), auto;    
}
.changed_cursor{
    cursor: url('images/changed.gif'), auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body id="body" class="default_cursor">
Content Here

<script>
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("body").classList.toggle("changed_cursor"); //Toggle cursor.
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```