# How to imitate touch cursor (circle) in CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, touch, mouse-cursor

I'm building a website which simulates a mobile device. I'd like to indicate this with a circle for a cursor, similar to when using the Dev Tools in mobile mode.

Is there a standard way to do this in CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: Are you talking about changing the cursor icon?

Comment: Yes. Like `cursor: pointer` but with a circle instead of a hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Comment: It does if that's the best way of solving the problem :)

Comment: Yes, it is the standard way

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("cursor")[0].style.transform = "translate(" + event.pageX + "px, " + event.pageY + "px)";
})

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("cursor")[0].classList.add("click")
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("cursor")[0].classList.remove("click")
  }, 250)
})
```

```css
.cursor {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0s;
}

.cursor.click {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: -12.5px;
  top: -12.5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: width 0.25s, height 0.25s, left 0.25s, top 0.25s, opacity 0.25s;
}
```

```html
Click anywhere to show click cursor!
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, no javascript required.

First of all download that round cursor in png or whatever format, then save that file let's say with a name of `cursor.png` then go to your main css and add this :

```
*, *::before, *::after {
   cursor : url('cursor.png'),default;
}
```

If nothing loads it'll load default cursor.

Then, now some webkits for cursor set them too according to you :

> `-webkit-zoom-in`
>
> `-webkit-zoom-out`
>
> `-webkit-zoom-grab`
>
> `-webkit-zoom-grabbing`