# how to use a png image as a cursor with vue

Tags: css, vue.js, url, cursor, vuetify.js

I want to use an image as a cursor in my vue app. I tried to do it as below:

```
<template>
  <v-app
    :style="{
      cursor:
        'url(' + require('@/assets/images/custom_cursor.png') + ')'
    }"
  >
```

When I write backgroundImage instead of cursor, the url works.

When I write 'circle' instead of url link for cursor, it also works.

But when I use the url for the cursor, it doesn't work.

Can anybody please help? I use Vuetify as a css framework by the way.

Note: I will make a dynamic class out of it using computed but I should figure out how to call an image as a cursor. My guess is that vuetify doesn't let an image through url overwrite the default cursor.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. Looks like this problem is related to webpack require call as the provided code should work AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first response so here goes nothing!

```
cursor:
    url(' + require('@/assets/images/custom_cursor.png') + ')
}"
```

Maybe removing the tick marks before and after the url?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to provide an explanation as to why so people in the future can also reference this and understand why in the future.