# Replace all cursor in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

How to replace all cursors with my custom image in tailwindcss?

**My attempt**

In tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      cursor: {
        default: "url(/images/cursor.png)",
        pointer: "url(/images/cursorPointer.png)",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**Answer:**

In global.css:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  @apply cursor-default;
}

a, button {
  @apply cursor-pointer;
}
```

In tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      cursor: {
        default: 'url(/images/cursor.png), default',
        pointer: 'url(/images/cursorPointer.png), pointer',
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Comment: That isn't using the tailwindcss "tailwind.config.js"

Comment: I was referring to the cause, that an image could not be used as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that your image is available? You could try using an external image instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<url>` value **must** be followed by a single keyword value:

```css
/* URL with mandatory keyword fallback */
cursor: url(/images/cursor.png), pointer;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#syntax

So, in your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      cursor: {
        default: 'url(/images/cursor.png), default',
        pointer: 'url(/images/cursor.png), pointer',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Nz8Ur49ENq

---

If you want to replace the cursor for all the elements in the page, a solution might be:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  @apply cursor-default;
}
```

Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/XdgFOu86ix?file=css

Comment: I saw in your code, you added the "cursor-point" class into <p class="ml-4 cursor-pointer">. Is it impossible to replace the default cursor without explicitly defining those classes into the elements? For example, my default <a>, https://play.tailwindcss.com/Kgc6pYAwEv, is still hand-pointer

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for your need: https://play.tailwindcss.com/XdgFOu86ix?file=css.

Comment: Thanks andreivictor for your answers. Looks like the only way to replace the pointers is by explicitly defining each and every element that has a pointer by defaults, and @apply cursor-pointer them. Example:
 a, button {
  {at}apply cursor-pointer;
}
Correct me if I'm wrong. Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/T2tZDAGnyt?file=css

Comment: indeed, I think that is the only solution.