# Custom cursor in CSS doesn't work even the size is 24px*24px (I'm doing it for a first time)

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
.cursor:hover {
    color: blue;
  cursor: url ("../img/cursor.jpeg"),pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid cursor">
    <div style="display:grid; background-color: deeppink; position: relative; margin:     10px; grid-area: product1; "><div style="position: absolute; margin: 0px;height: 146.66px;" class="griditem2">product 1</div></div>
    <div style="display:grid; background-color: orangered; margin: 10px; grid-area: product2;"><div class="griditem">product 2</div></div>
    <div style="display:grid; background-color: deeppink; margin: 10px; grid-area: product3;"><div class="griditem2">product 3</div></div>
    <div style="display:grid; background-color: orangered; margin: 10px; grid-area: product4;"><div class="griditem">product 4</div></div>
    <div style="display:grid; background-color: deeppink; margin: 10px; grid-area: product5;"><div class="griditem2">product 5</div></div>
    <div style="display:grid; background-color: orangered; margin: 10px;grid-area:  product6"><div class="griditem">product 6</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Comment: Can you explain what is your issue exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a space between url and your parenthesis that's causing the problem.

Try `cursor: url("../img/cursor.jpeg"), pointer;`