# Google Chrome won't show CSS image cursor

Tags: html, css

I am using this script to have a custom cursor for my website, but it won't work. I have already tried to use a smaller image, but also that won't work. Can anyone tell me how to fix this small issue?

Here's the relevant HTML:

```html
<div style="cursor: url('cursor.png'), grab;">
<p> lorum ipsum </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you host the image on something like imgur?

Comment: is it smaller than 32x32? if not, make sure it's smaller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)