# Custom cursor not appearing [ CSS ]

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I am using a custom cursor with .cur file type and its not showing when i use CSS cursor property

## CSS

```
body {
  cursor: url('/assets/cursor/cursor.cur'), auto;
}
```

`This only displays the default cursor throughout the whole webpage. Please look into the problem.`

##### Thank You!

Tried many times by changing the cursor image path and changing the format in which url is entered but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Do you see the browser _request_ that resource in the dev tools network panel? And if so, what response does it get?

Comment: I think some combination of browser/settings may prevent this. Having tested a few (e.g. the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)) none of the `url()` based cursors are displayed for me.