# Custom cursor property not working IE browser

Tags: css

I used the custom cursor property for the task, but it does not work with ie browsers. I used the following snippet.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom Cursor</title>
<style>
h1{
cursor: url(http://www.franco.it/Images/Lookf.png), auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Custom Cursor</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari - everything except IE. Some articles say I should use the `.cur` format but how do I convert an image to cur?  I couldn't find a proper link to convert it.

Thanks.

Comment: may be because IE sucks....what IE version are you talking anyway???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419314/custom-cursor-image-doesnt-work-in-all-ies

Comment: Windows Internet Explorer 9 and later: When specifying a custom cursor via url(), you must provide at least one "fallback" cursor in addition to the custom cursor, or the custom cursor will not render correctly. For instance, "cursor: url(cursors/cursor2.ani), pointer". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Cursor creators: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/controlling-cursors-with-css-and-creating-cur-files/ or http://download.cnet.com/RealWorld-Cursor-Editor/3000-2094_4-10550991.html?tag=dropDownForm;productListing FYI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE doesn't support png format for cursor.

You need convert to "cur" format.

The css code will look like this

```
h1{cursor: url(http://myworkstudio.com/app/cursor1.cur), pointer}
```

You can refer below url:

http://chevronscode.com/index.php/ie-custom-cursor.html