# Custom mouse pointer not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to implement a custom cursor which is not working in IE11. 
This is working fine in chrome. Can someone help me to make it work in Internet Explorer 11

The style I am using is

```
cursor : url("../img/cursor-grab.gif"), url("../img/cursor-grab-cur.cur"), move
```

You can see the page here : http://us.accept.kia.eu/us/models/kia-sorento-2014/
There will be a car titles 360 View.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419314/custom-cursor-image-doesnt-work-in-all-ies

Comment: @Luis P. A. there is nothing related to IE11

Comment: ?? all IEs , means IE6 to IE11

Comment: I dint mention it but yeah its not working in all IE

Answer (score 4):

Per the MSDN reference page for the [cursor property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx), IE supports only .cur and .ani files.

You can see this for yourself using [one of the samples](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/cursor_c.htm) listed on the reference page.  It's a bit wonky, though.  You have to select a cursor and then apply it in order to verify the functionality.

Also, you should note that caniuse.com suggests that the [original values](http://caniuse.com/#search=cursor) of the CSS3 cursor property are more widely supported than newer values.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance