# How to add a custom cursor in html / hta

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hta

I'm making a create an avatar game for kids and I want to add a cute heart cursor. The dimensions of the cursor is 32x32. I'm making this with HTA. I've done custom cursors many times, so I don't see why it's not working now.

```
body{
cursor:url('heartcursor.png'), auto;
}
```

If anyone could help me, that would be great!

Comment: Check if the image file is in the same directory.

Comment: Try ./heartcursor.png

Comment: MSHTA uses the IE9 Browser Engine so [this is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701235/692942) - *” Cursors of type .CUR and .ANI are the only supported cursor types.”*

Answer (score -1):

I try to refer the documentation and found that Internet Explorer only supports **.cur** or **.ani** files for cursor.

> url(uri) : Internet Explorer 6 and later. Cursor is defined by the
>   author, using a custom URI, such as url('mycursor.cur'). Cursors of
>   type .CUR and .ANI are the only supported cursor types.

Reference:

[Cursor Property for IE browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa358795(v=vs.94)#MainContent)

I tested with .cur file and it works fine with IE.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
cursor:url("arrow.cur"), auto;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
sample page...<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Footer
</body>
</html>
```

[Cursor file downloaded from here.](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-detail/130425)

Output in IE 11:

[image]

I also tested this example with IE document mode IE5, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11. It works without any issue.

Comment: As [the duplicate already points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23065580/692942), you want to leave an answer go leave it there.